# Unable to view django website - development server

Tags: django

Upon running the the dev server 0.0.0.0:8000, I cannot see the website loaded in the browser.

While going through some of the reasons why this might happen, I have done the following changes:

- ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
- Killed all processes on 8000
- firewall turned off

The server I am working on is RHEL.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 01, 2019 - 04:39:38
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'gig_bank.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

//Nothing is displayed in the browser.

Comment: What you see when you navigate to http://0.0.0.0:8000/ in browser. Is it blank page?

Comment: it says : This site can’t be reached

Comment: Even when i run on ip it whould still show : this site cant be reached

Comment: can you show full console trace when you run your server.

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 01, 2019 - 05:14:40
Django version 2.1.7, using settings 'big_bank.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Comment: It's ok with django server. You do something wrong when you enter ip on browser. Try to visit the ip by clicking from django server.

Comment: i have entered the correct ip with the post 8000...

Comment: can you go by clicking from django server?

Comment: Is it a local server on your machine or a remote server?

Comment: its a remote server

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified that it's a remote server, it most likely be a firewall issue,
you need to make sure `port 8000` is open, you could test it using `netcat` as following :

```
nc -zv -w1 ip port
```

> if the server is inside a cloud you need to add the rule to your cloud console, turning off the firewall in the server won't suffice.

- Just in case the firewall on the server wasn't actually off, you could run `sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp` (For linux user)

Comment: just to make sure that it not a network issue, can you run `nc -l -p 8000` instead of django on the remote server, the run `echo 'Hello' | nc ip port` on your computer, So I suggest a different possibility